# concat string and sort vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string, sorting, arraylist

I have 4 textboxs in sequence for user to input string. If the string contains comma, it'll be spilt. For each string, it'll concat with next string with a Dash. To visualize this problem:

```
Dim str1 = "A1,A2"
Dim str2 = "2,3"
Dim str3 = "4A,4B"
Dim str4 = "7,8"
```

Format:
str1 & "-" & str2 & "-" & str3 & "-" & str4

the output will be (in Ascending sequence):

```
{"A1-2-4A-7", "A1-2-4A-8", "A1-2-4B-7", "A1-2-4B-8",
"A1-3-4A-7", "A1-3-4A-8", "A1-3-4B-7", "A1-3-4B-8",
"A2-2-4A-7", "A2-2-4A-8", "A2-2-4B-7", "A2-2-4B-8",
"A2-3-4A-7", "A2-3-4A-8", "A2-3-4B-7", "A2-3-4B-8"}
```

If no comma, it'll be treated as single string.

I managed to achieve the above result with:

```
Private Sub GenerateString(ByVal str1 As String, ByVal str2 As String, ByVal str3 As String, ByVal str4 As String)
    Dim arr1 As New List(Of String)
    Dim arr2 As New List(Of String)
    Dim arr3 As New List(Of String)
    Dim arr4 As New List(Of String)

    SpliString(str1, arr1)
    SpliString(str2, arr2)
    SpliString(str3, arr3)
    SpliString(str4, arr4)

    Dim arrMain As New ArrayList

    arrMain.Add(arr1)
    arrMain.Add(arr2)
    arrMain.Add(arr3)
    arrMain.Add(arr4)

    Dim listCom As New List(Of String)
    For Each tempList As List(Of String) In arrMain
        If tempList.Count > 0 Then
            If listCom.Count = 0 Then
                listCom.AddRange(tempList)
            Else
                Dim listTemp As New List(Of String)
                listTemp.AddRange(listCom)
                listCom.Clear()
                For Each tempStrMain As String In listTemp
                    For Each tempStr As String In tempList
                        listCom.Add(tempStrMain & "-" & tempStr)
                    Next
                Next
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Return listCom
End Function

Private Sub SpliString(ByVal strToSplit As String, ByRef arrString As List(Of String))
    If Not strToSplit = "" Then
        If strToSplit.Contains(",") Then
            Dim splitArr() As String = strToSplit.Split(",")

            For Each str As String In splitArr
                arrString.Add(str)
            Next
        Else
            arrString.Add(strToSplit)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Now my question is, how do I able to sort the string by the group of the string?
For example, if str3 is the selected group of strings at top, it'll be:

the output will be (by the 3rd string group):

```
"A1-2-4A-7", "A1-2-4A-8", "A1-3-4A-7", "A1-3-4A-8", 
"A2-2-4A-7", "A2-2-4A-8", "A2-3-4A-7", "A2-3-4A-8",
"A1-2-4B-7", "A1-2-4B-8", "A1-3-4B-7", "A1-3-4B-8",
"A2-2-4B-7", "A2-2-4B-8", "A2-3-4B-7", "A2-3-4B-8"
```

if str4 is the selected group to sort, output:

```
"A1-2-4A-7", "A1-2-4B-7", "A1-3-4A-7", "A1-3-4B-7", 
"A2-2-4A-7", "A2-2-4B-7", "A2-3-4A-7", "A2-3-4B-7",
"A1-2-4A-8", "A1-2-4B-8", "A1-3-4A-8", "A1-3-4B-8",
"A2-2-4A-8", "A2-2-4B-8", "A2-3-4A-8", "A2-3-4B-8"
```

Any method like using DataTable, ArrayList, IComparer?
And also, is there a better way to rewrite the GenerateString code? It'll be better if the code dynamic enough to support n inputs (which currently I hard-coded as 4) too.

Comment: Fix syntax errors. Declared as `arr1` but used as `arrStr1`...

Comment: Don't use `ArrayList`, rather use `List(Of List(Of String))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my first attempt at your answer.  Unfortunately, it is not dynamic yet.  It uses LINQ and its cross join abilities to get to your answer.

```
  Private Sub btnMiscTest_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles btnMiscTest.Click
    Dim str1 As String = "A1,A2"
    Dim str2 As String = "2,3"
    Dim str3 As String = "4A,4B"
    Dim str4 As String = "7,8"

    'Add the strings into a list
    Dim multiString As New List(Of String)
    multiString.Add(str1)
    multiString.Add(str2)
    multiString.Add(str3)
    multiString.Add(str4)

    Dim resultStrings As List(Of String) = GenerateString(multiString, 3)
  End Sub


  Private Function GenerateString(ByVal multiString As List(Of String), ByVal sortIndex As Integer) As List(Of String)
    'Split each string into a list of strings and add it to a "StringOfStrings" list
    Dim tmpStringOfStrings As New List(Of List(Of String))
    For Each tmpString As String In multiString
      Dim tmpSubString As List(Of String) = tmpString.Split(",").ToList
      tmpStringOfStrings.Add(tmpSubString)
    Next
    'Use LINQ to do a Cross Apply and sort by index
    Dim resultList As List(Of String) = (From s0 As String In tmpStringOfStrings(0) _
                                         From s1 As String In tmpStringOfStrings(1) _
                                         From s2 As String In tmpStringOfStrings(2) _
                                         From s3 As String In tmpStringOfStrings(3) _
                                         Order By If(sortIndex = 0, s0, _
                                                  If(sortIndex = 1, s1, _
                                                  If(sortIndex = 2, s2, s3))) _
                                         Select s0 & "-" & s1 & "-" & s2 & "-" & s3).ToList
    Return resultList
  End Function
```